Flutter In app purchase production build rejected
Flutter In App purchases production build rejected due to recept validation issue.
Following is the response from appstore.
“When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.”
Can anyone help me for the correct approach for validating this?

if everything is fine from your side, just tell apple that app is made using flutter.
